# Base64 in css? How to see the code

Tags: css, base64

In a CSS file for a script I bought I am seeing three lines that have me somewhat worried:

```
.h5video .control-panel { height: 45px; width:100%; line-height: 45px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAtCAYAAABvewHEAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAEdJREFUeNpiYGBg2Mzg6+v7iunu3bt/mIBcBqb///8jE//+/cPOJZaFkwDbxggEIOI/iGCAE4wQFhAw4GIxYZWFcSEGAAQYAB5zRmw2StEiAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent; position: absolute;  }


.h5video .control-panel .seek-bar-guage { height: 7px; background: url("data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAICAAAAAAdccqdAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAABdJREFUCB1j+M/0g+kr02emj0D4mekrAD41B7hJ9Jz5AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent/* #C9DD1A */; width: 0%; left: 0px; z-index: 2; position: absolute; z-index: 0; }
.h5video .control-panel .seek-bar-buffer { height: 7px; width: 0px; top:0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 0; background: url(data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAICAIAAAC3eAIWAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAACFJREFUeNpiyMrKYvrz5w/Tr1+/wPjnz59w/Pv3b4AAAwBFtxXP00sbFwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==); }
```

These all show Base64 in the coding and I'm trying to figure out what it actually should be showing there.  Can anyone help with this?

Comment: @Mihir you can't accept answers until like 15 minutes after the question in posted.

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing are base64 encoded images. You can decode them and have them written to files with a .png extension to see their contents. The advantage of base64 encoded images within the CSS is that they can reduce the number of requests that the browser has to make to the web server for loading a page.

Comment: Oh ok, so that wouldn't be calling an external image from another website or anything like that, right?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't respond earlier - I didn't have commenting privileges till recently.

Yes, if you have an image in base64 encoding within the CSS or HTML, the browser doesn't have to fetch it from the other website (applies even if the image is on your own web site).

When you include a base64 image within CSS or an HTML file, you are serving the image within the same request i.e. the web browser does not have to make another request to the web server to obtain the image. You can include small images within the HTML or CSS (base64 encoded) to reduce the number of roundtrips to the web server.